# Proof that $(abc)^2 = \frac{(c^6-a^6-b^6)}{3}$

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification, proof-explanation

We are given the length of the sides of a right triangle T, where $a \leq b \leq c$. We are asked to prove if $T$ is a right triangle. then $(abc)^2 = (c^6-a^6-b^6)/3$.

What I tried:
I tried substituting with the Pythagorean theorem $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$.

Where I am stuck:
I am unable to get $\frac{1}{3}$ or $3$ anywhere in my simplification. Is there some kind of identity that I am missing?

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "substituting". From Pythagoras you have an equation with powers of $a,$ $b,$ and $c.$ Did you use that to substitute for one of the variables $a,$ $b,$, or $c$? If so, which one? (Substituting to eliminate $c$ from the requested equation would have led to something like one of the two answers already given--at least you would have had to cube $(a^2 + b^2)$ and would have found at least one $3.$)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with $$c^2=a^2+b^2$$ the left-hand side is given by
$$(ab\sqrt{a^2+b^2})^2$$ and the other side
$$\frac{(\sqrt{a^2+b^2})^6-a^6-b^6}{3}$$
can you compute this?
expanding the right-hand side we get $$a^4b^2+a^2b^4$$ and so is the left-hand side.

Answer (score 3):

Hint : Cube the equation $\color{blue}{a^2+b^2=c^2}$
\begin{eqnarray*}
a^6+b^6+\color{red}{3} a^2 b^2 (\color{blue}{a^2+b^2}) =c^6.
\end{eqnarray*}